# set all values in multidimensional array to 0 if they don;t meet certain criteria

Tags: r, arrays

if I have a 2d array:

## Create two vectors of different lengths.

```
vector1 <- c(5,9,3)
vector2 <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)

# Take these vectors as input to the array.
result <- array(c(vector1,vector2),dim = c(3,3,2))

result
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10   13
[2,]    9   5    14
[3,]    3   12   15

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7   8    14
[2,]    9   7    14
[3,]    1   12   22
```

How can I set all values in the 2d array to 0 if the values in `result[,,1] != 5` and values in `result[,,2] =! 7`. i.e. only two values should remain - `1,1` and `2,2` so that I am left with:

```
result
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   0   0
[2,]    0   5   0
[3,]    0   0   0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7   0    0
[2,]    0   7    0
[3,]    0   0    0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a logical expression, `replicate` it to an `array` based on the `length` of the third dimension and multiply (`*`)

```
i1 <- ((result[,,1] == 5)|(result[,,2] == 7))
result * replicate(dim(result)[3], i1)
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    0    0
#[2,]    0    5    0
#[3,]    0    0    0

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    7    0    0
#[2,]    0    7    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
vals <- c(5, 7)
for(i in seq_len(dim(result)[3])) {
     result[,,i] <- result[,,i] *(result[,,i] == vals[i])
   }
```

#### data

```
result <- array(c(5, 9, 3, 10, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7, 9, 1, 8, 7, 
       12, 14, 14, 22), dim = c(3, 3, 2))
```